# This redirect loop is eating my lunch!

Tags: redirect

I recently transferred a domain to my own registrar and web-host and set it up to point to a subdirectory that I'd setup beforehand to get it looking and working like it should.

Since the transfer was conmplete, I'm now getting redirect error looping with 301 permanent redirect.

I've tried every resource I can to no avail and need to get some extra eyes on this, because I don't want change so much that it renders the setup in the subdirectory useless even though I make periodic copies.

The site is https://kentuckianacontractors.com/

and .htaccess currently looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.kentuckianacontractors\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And my `wp-config.php` currently has these settings:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false );
/* define('MULTISITE', true); */
/* define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true); */
/* define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'kentuckianacontractors.com'); */
/* define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/'); */
/* define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); */
/* define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); */

define('WP_HOME','https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com');  define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com'); 
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com' );

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 

/* define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/'); */
/* define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', ''); */
/* define('COOKIEPATH', ''); */
/* define('SITECOOKIEPATH', ''); */

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Steve D.

Comment: Correction: the site is https: // www.kentuckianacontractors.com

Comment: are you using cloudflare? if so your setting are probably incompatible

Comment: ^- this. OP is using Cloudflare. If your host is not providing SSL certificates, you can use [the Cloudflare flexible SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/) plugin

Comment: Agree with the others, if I `curl -Ik https://kentuckianacontractors.com/` I get a 301 to `https://kentuckianacontractors.com/` and if I `curl -Ik https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com/` I get a 301 to `https://www.kentuckianacontractors.com/` I think your best bet is to resolve this with the Cloudflare people.